# How convert to utf8 string in c++

Tags: c++, string, utf-8

I have a string output that ins not necessarily valid utf8. I have to pass it to a method only accepting valid utf8 strings.
Therefore I need to convert output to the closest valid utf8 string removing invalid bytes or parts. How can I do that in c++? I would like not to use a 3rd party library.

Comment: I think this is not safe. If your string is not UTF-8, the only safe thing is to abort entirely. Otherwise you're opening yourself up to attacks.

Comment: What does *invalid bytes* mean for you ? Do you want a valid utf-8 stream (with maybe invalid codepoints or non-sensical combinations) or a valid unicode utf-8 encoded stream ?

Comment: i need a valid unicode utf-8 encoded stream... remove everything that is not valid.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for UTF-8 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) contains a lot of information that should easily help you accomplish this.

Comment: @Component 10 - "easily" sounds an overly optimistic.

Comment: @KerrekSB: if "removing some bytes" results in a valid UTF-8 string that can be used in an attack, what stops the attacker from just providing that same valid string in the first place to perform the same attack? Removing invalid sequences could allow attacks by indirectly creating some other defect, though. For example if you measure the length before removing bytes and forget to update it, or other such error that would be impossible without the step that modifies the input data.

Comment: @SteveJessop: No no, the attack isn't in the *valid* string, but in the way you attempt to recover from *invalid* data. This has happened before, and as a result, the Unicode standard now says that an application should give up immediately upon encountering an invalid byte.

Comment: @KerreSB: that seems to pre-suppose that every conceivable algorithm for removing bad data is exploitable. I can think of good reasons not to try to recover from bad data (you have no way of knowing what string was intended, so why bother guessing). This supposed inevitability of exploits if I do isn't one them.

Comment: @SChepurin: That's fair enough I suppose. In fact, the problem here is knowing what the input is - converting to UTF-8 really should be quite easy *if* the input is known, but when all that's to go on is that it's *not necessarily valid utf8* I don't think you can even begin.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The Unicode standard doesn't say "that an application should give up immediately upon encountering an invalid byte" Unicode 6.1.0 3.2 Conformance Requirements C10: "When a process interprets a code unit sequence which purports to be in a Unicode character encoding form, it shall treat ill-formed code unit sequences as an error condition and shall not interpret such sequences as characters." [...] "—for example, by signaling an error, filtering the code unit out, or representing the code unit with a marker such as U+FFFD replacement character."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `icu::UnicodeString` methods `fromUTF8(const StringPiece &utf8)` or `toUTF8String(StringClass &result).`

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure your string is valid UTF-8 with only a few corrupt bytes, http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/ can fix that. From the page:
`#include "utf8.h"
void fix_utf8_string(std::string& str) {
    std::string temp;
    utf8::replace_invalid(str.begin(), str.end(), back_inserter(temp));
    str = temp;
}`

Your requirement for not using a 3rd party library is pretty much impossible when dealing with Unicode data, but the UTF8-CPP library is header-only which is as light as you can get.